# How do I implement a way for the customer to submit a coupon (cart rule) code in PrestaShop 1.6?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I cannot find any ready-made coupon field in the default PrestaShop theme or a controller that takes care of the entire process, but I can find the associated methods in the `CartRule` class. To avoid having to call the class methods manually one-by-one, is there a controller that takes care of this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Field on frontend in *shopping-cart.tpl* with id *discount_name*.
On backend *ParentOrderController* method *init* handle it.